# Visualization of tracks of objects in images by superposition

Tags: image-processing

I have sets of images (each contains about 3000 images where many objects are seen, each image is 4 Megapixels large, format is 8bit, gray scale, png).

**To get an impression about the trajectories of the objects I superpose all images and produce a single colorized image where the objects in each image have a specific color corresponding to the image number.**

The background ist black, the tracks start with blue and stop with red.

**The problem in the code below is that it crashes when many and larges images are used since all of them are read at once in memory.**

**Is there a solution that image by image can be read and superposed on top of each other**, instead of reading them at once?

**example image** that contains only a single object:

[image]

a **sample of small images** for testing the code: http://tinyurl.com/ht5362l

**code:**

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[imageDir], "Directory"], Dynamic[imageDir]}];
SetDirectory[imageDir];

fNames = FileNames["*.png"];
numImages = Length[fNames];

colTable = {
   {Black}, 
      Table[
         {Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]}, 
         {x, 2/numImages, 1, 1/numImages}
      ]
}; 

colTable = Flatten[colTable];

threshold = FindThreshold[Import[fNames[[1]], Method -> "Entropy"]];

bins = Table[
          Clip[
             Import[fNames[[i]], "GrayLevels"], {threshold, threshold}, 
             {0, i/numImages}
          ], 
          {i, 1, numImages}
       ];

superImg = Colorize[
              Image[
                 Map[Max, Transpose[bins, {3, 1, 2}], {2}]
              ], 
              ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &)
           ]
```

**superposed image:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assemble the `bins` image one layer at a time. E.g. after computing `threshold` do

```
bins = 0;
Do[
  m = Clip[Import[fNames[[i]], "GrayLevels"], {threshold, threshold}, {0, 1}];
  bins = bins (1 - m) + m i/numImages,
  {i, 1, numImages}];

superImg = Colorize[Image[bins], ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: This is the solution ... probably there is no other way than to do it via a loop? For 10 images of 4 Megapixel `AbsoluteTiming` yields about 10 sec for my computer.

Comment: The timing will be dominated by the image import, there's probably no easy way to speed it up.

Comment: You think therefore also compiling would not improve the speed?

Answer (score 7):

I propose making use of `ComponentMeasurements`, especially the "Centroid"-Option of `MorphologicalComponents`, which calculates the center-of-mass, might be very convenient.

For example you might try the following:

```
SetDirectory[imageDir]
i = Import["2016071.gif"];
length = Length[i];
m[y_] := Module[{y0}, y0 = y;
  iframe = i[[y]];
  (*Poisson-Filter blures the image, edges are contained*)
  res = TotalVariationFilter[iframe, 0.35, Method -> "Poisson"];
  mean = ImageMeasurements[iframe, "MeanIntensity"];
  ib = MorphologicalBinarize[res, {mean + 0.5}];
  (*Delete Small Components  if necessary!*)
  delsmall = DeleteSmallComponents[ib, 10];
  t = MorphologicalComponents[delsmall] // Max;
  m1 = ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalComponents[delsmall], 
     "Centroid"] /. Rule[_, x_] -> x;
  imageBuffer = iframe;
  If[y == 1, pointsbuffer = SetAlphaChannel[iframe, 0], 
   pointsbuffer = pointsbuffer;
   (*In each frame a loop will set dots a each com-
   position calculated*)
   For[p = 1, p < t + 1, p++, Print[p];
     points = 
      Show[pointsbuffer, 
       Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], ColorData["SolarColors"][y/50], 
         Point[Part[m1, p]]}]];
     pointsbuffer = points]
    (*Print to see the output on-the-fly*)
    Print[Show[iframe, pointsbuffer, ImageSize -> 350]]
    Export["outputDir/img_" <> ToString[y] <> ".png", 
     Show[iframe, pointsbuffer]]
   ]
  ]
(*Run through all frames*)
For[k = 1, k <= length, k++,
 m[k]
 ]
```

I should notice that I made a .gif out of your images.
This code might not be the most efficient or beautiful, since it is written quite quickly. There is definetly room for improvement, but I think it is at least understandable.

My output looks like this (quality is reduced):

[image: Output of ComponentMeasurements]

P.S. If you want to know more about the procedure itself you might also consider printing "ib", which is the morphologically binarized image. By doing so one can see which component/area is used to calculate the center-of-mass.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. What I wanted was to have a quick overview on how objects move in an image with time without determining their position. What would you do if many object are seen?

Comment: If you are not interested in the center-of-mass but rather in an overview, you can also drop the "Centroid"-measurement and instead overlay the binarized images by `MorphologicalBinarize`. You will end up with a solution very similar to what you have done before in the opening-thread. This will also work with many objects. By the way, the code in my main thread will also work with more than one object!

Comment: Incidentally, you might also be interested in [`ImageFeatureTrack`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFeatureTrack.html). For instance you might choose the initial positions either by yourself or even by using `MorphologicalComponents` and `ImageFeatureTrack` might track those objects during your movie.

Comment: Please see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120039/can-imagefeaturetrack-be-used-to-track-the-intensitycentroid-of-objects. For accurate scientific subpixel measurements where it is necessary to define the method on how objects positions should be determined and tracked `ImageFeatureTrack` cannot be used.